# Transpose rows to columns - pivot in SQL Server 2008 using an id column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table with columns `logid`, `skilllevel`, `logskill` and a sample of data looks like this:

```
logid  skilllevel  logonskill  skillposition
--------------------------------------------
101    90          1           1
101    40          2           2
102    30          4           1
```

I want to get it arranged like the following:

```
logid  skilllevel1  skilllevel2 skilllevel3 logonskill1 logonskill2 logonskill3 
101    90           40          60          1           2           3
102    30           20          10          4           5           6
```

`skilllevel1` corresponds to `logonskill1` as so on `skillposition` is the substring of `logonskill`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    select logid, skilllevel val, 'skilllevel' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,skillposition) colName  from MyTable
    UNION ALL 
    select logid, logonskill val, 'logonskill' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,skillposition) colName  from MyTable
) SRC
PIVOT (MAX(val) FOR colName IN ([skilllevel1],[skilllevel2],[skilllevel3],[logonskill1],[logonskill2],[logonskill3])) AS PVT
```